# How to change Konsole tab icon?

Tags: kde, icons, konsole

In previous versions of Konsole, I could set a custom icon for a Konsole tab using

```
echo -e "\033]32;/path/to/file.svg\007"    # from Bash
print(f"\033]32;{iconPath}\007", end="")   # from Python
```

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04, which ships with Konsole 19.12.3 (Plasma 5.18.5), and this does not work anymore. No errors, but no change in the icon.

I know that the [default tab icon has been removed](https://phabricator.kde.org/D17747) at some point, but how do we set icons for individual tabs now? The only way I can see is to select an icon for the whole profile, which is not what I need.

---

**Update:** As it turns out, I can now get the icon to display, but only if I turn the terminal bell back on. I have had `set bell-style none` in my `.inputrc` for almost 20 years, so that was the last thing I would have thought of. The bell style must be `audible` (the default setting), `visible` does not work. With this setting, my custom icon will show up after Konsole has displayed and cleared its built-in bell icon on the tab at least once.

This still doesn't look quite right to me, but at least there's some progress.